# Two select2 works properly but it does not get data from ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have two select2 dropdowns which both can recognize select2 and its options, but none of the ajax works.
if anyone can help please share your ideas with me to find out how should I fix this problem
Here are jquery codes

```js
<script>

$("#process").select2({
        placeholder: "Process",
        ajax: {
            url: URL,

            "headers": {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('api_token')
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            processResults: function(data) {
                var json = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < data.data.length; j++) {
                    var config = {
                        id: '',
                        text: '',
                        title: '',
                        value: '',
                    };
                    config.id = data.data[j].id;
                    config.text = data.data[j].code;
                    config.title = data.data[j].title;
                    config.icon = 'role';
                    json.push(config);
                }

                return {
                    results: json
                };
            }
        }
    });
    
    $("#receiver").select2({
        placeholder: "Receiver",
        ajax: {
            url: URL,
            "headers": {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('api_token')
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            processResults: function (data) {
                // Tranforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
                var json = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < data.data.roles.length; j++) {
                    var config = {
                        id: '',
                        text: ''
                    };
                    config.id = data.data.roles[j].id;
                    config.text = data.data.roles[j].name;
                    json.push(config);
                }
                for (var k = 0; k < data.data.users.length; k++) {
                    var config = {
                        id: '',
                        text: ''
                    };
                    config.id = data.data.users[k].id;
                    config.text = data.data.users[k].name;
                    config.icon = 'user';
                    json.push(config);
                }

                return {
                    results: json
                };
            }
            // Additional AJAX parameters go here; see the end of this chapter for the full code of this example
        },
    });

</script>
```

```html
<select class="form-control m-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="receiver"></select>

<select class="form-control m-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="process"></select>
```

other options of select2 work properly but ajax do not get data.
If anyone has any idea please share it with me

Comment: Can you share a codepen or something like that

Comment: https://codepen.io/niaz1374/pen/xxOyozB here is my code pen

Comment: It looks like you use double quotes around Bearer and those should be single.

Comment: @NiazEstefaie ️ it's need to be a working demo please add AJAX URL and a token so that we can debug.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA please check it and tell me does it work for you like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem and I should get .select2 in a setTimeout function.

```js
<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#id").select2()
  }, 1000)
</script>
```